# How is my for-loop messing up?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, struct

I am having a problem with my for loops in this code that I've written. Everything runs fine except it does not catch the value for the 4th row in my string array ("Jill", "Jason", "Jim".)

I'm pretty sure the problem is happening in my function definition for 'Initialize' since the values for the final ID and final list of team members is not being caught by my vector. For reference, the output is fine up until the final TeamV element. I've tried messing with the indices a ton but I've hit a brick wall so-to-speak. Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    const int NUM_TEAMS = 4;
    const int NUM_MEMBERS = 3;

    struct TeamS {
        int id;
        string m[NUM_MEMBERS];

    }TeamV, tempTeam;

    void Initialize(vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[],
        const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize);

    void printList(const vector <TeamS> & TeamV);

    int main()
    {
        const int ID[NUM_TEAMS] = { 123, 321, 456, 789 };

        const string MEMBERS[NUM_TEAMS][NUM_MEMBERS] =
        {
        { "Sarah", "Joe", "John" },
        { "Chris", "Kevin", "James" },
        { "Tom", "Kim", "Emily" },
        { "Jill", "Jason", "Jim" }
        };

        vector<TeamS> TeamV;

        Initialize(TeamV, ID, MEMBERS, NUM_TEAMS);
        cout << TeamV[3].m[1];
        printList(TeamV);

        // not working on my installation at home  -> system("pause");
        cin.get();



    }

    void Initialize(vector<TeamS>& TeamV, const int id[], const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize)
    {
        //Resizes a TeamS vector and then modifies it's values to match the information provided
        TeamV.resize(arraySize+1);

        //iterate through teams
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize+1; i++)
        {

            TeamV[i].id = id[i];

            //iterate through members of teams
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MEMBERS; j++)
            {
                TeamV[i].m[j] = m[i][j];
            }

        }
    }


    void printList(const vector<TeamS>& TeamV)
    {
        cout << "**** Team List ****\n\n";
        int teamVSize = TeamV.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < teamVSize; i++)
        {
            cout << "Information for team " + to_string(i) << endl;
            cout << "ID:\t" << TeamV[i].id << "\t";

            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MEMBERS; j++)
            {
                cout << TeamV[i].m[j] << "\t";
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does you debugger tell you? If you don't know how to debug: Step 1) ***Learn to debug!***

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop goes out of bounds of the array. Get rid of `+1`

`for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

You pass in a 2D array with 4 rows, yet in your initialise() function you loop 5 times:

```
TeamV.resize(arraySize + 1); // Why plus 1?

    //iterate through teams
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize + 1; i++)  // Why plus 1?
        {

            TeamV[i].id = id[i];

            //iterate through members of teams
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_MEMBERS; j++)
            {
                TeamV[i].m[j] = m[i][j]; // Because you loop four times on the 
                                        // last loop i = 4, which is outside the string 
                                        // array you passed, which has only 4 rows. 
            }
        }
```

Zero index is the first, index i = 4 means the 5th row, you overrun the array you created, I get an std::bad_alloc exception.

If you leave out the + 1 from "arraySize + 1" it works fine.

By the way, the way it is now, it fills in correctly the 4 rows up until it throws the bad_alloc exception, so I don't understand why you said it leaves out the 4th row.

Comment: I ran the program without the +1 and still got the same result. https://imgur.com/roVxOOI

There's my output for reference. The only reason I put the +1 was to check my bounds and make sure I wasn't undershooting, must have forgotten to change it back. I agree that it should work that's why I'm stuck.

Comment: @user8585343 Copy your code in your question, go to http://www.cpp.sh/ paste it there, take away both "+1"s that you have in your initialize() function, run it and see what you get. You also have two objects after your struct TeamS declaration, TeamV, and tempTeam, get rid of them.

Comment: Huh wow. Thanks I think I probably need to reinstall VS, these kinds of bugs aren't too rare.